# how i can translate site to other language?

Tags: machine-translation

I build all my farm Hierarchy ( site-collections ,sites,libraries and columns library ) in English language and now i want to show it for end user in French language 
for example : i want to show  "add document to library" windows in French
and very important column names is show in French
what is the best way to do that with SharePoint 2010 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the language pack - install it like any other SharePoint update (you have to run PSConfig after - again like normal update).

After that you can enable the language in your site collection settings and it will be available for users to select (click on the arrow next to your name).  This does not change everything - only system strings.

If you want a "French" site you need to create one - set the default language and update your content (It will not translate your content).